# Choose Different properties according to firebase styled components reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, styled-components

I tried to find a solution to color the background of my  according to the value with styled components but I can't find it.

I use this to retrieve the data in my database

```
 function getOrders(uid) {
fire.firestore().collection("orders")

.where('uid', '==', `${uid}`)
.where("statut", "==", 'Terminé')
.onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {
  setOrders(
    querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
      id: doc.id,
      orderid: doc.data().id,
      statut: doc.data().statut,
      nomproduit: doc.data().nomproduit,
      type: doc.data().type
      
    }))
  );
    });
  }
```

I use this to set up my css for Projettype

```
 export const Projettype = styled.div`
 background-color:#d6f5fa;
  padding: 7px;
 border-radius: 13px;
 font-weight: bold;
  color: #7abeca;
  max-width:120px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:15px;
`;
```

What I would like is that if in my database status == In review, I can choose a color, == complete another color, and finish another one by passing the properties to my styled components.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Please include in your question where you are rendering a `Projettype` component and attempting to pass props to it. What colors are you trying to use for each case? Please try to be as detailed as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

```
  <ProjetCard type={order.type} key={order.id}>
```

You have to add a props ID in the container where you want to change the color here it's "type".

Then, Just add the conditions in styled components.

```
export const ProjetCard = styled.div`
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;

  &:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  }

  ${props => {
        if (props.type === 'Adcopy') return `
            background-color: #d6f5fa;
       
    `
    else if (props.type === 'Miniature') return `
        background-color: #f9abaf;
      
    `

    else if (props.type === 'Fiche Produit') return `
        background-color: #dde0fa;
        
    `
    else if (props.type === 'Vidéo') return `
        background-color: #fff3e0;
       
    `
    } 
  }
`;
```